# Return all rows with the same ID only if the "modifier" column for any of these rows contains a specific value

Tags: sql

I have not been able to figure out the following:

> If the column named Modifier 1, Modifier 2 or Modifier contains 11, and the procedure code is 777, return all rows with the same claim id and same date of service.

The Modifier, Procedure Code, DOS and Claim ID are all on the same table.

[image: Claim Table]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you stuck on a particular part of a query?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  What is the highlighting supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.claim_id = t.claim_id and 
                    t2.date_of_service = t.date_of_service and
                    11 in (t2.modifier1, t2.modifer2, t2.modifier3)
             );
```